# .htaccess issue with href #

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have working on my site and at the same time want to develop the .htaccess file

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^home?$    index.php    [NC,L]

RewriteRule    ^hk/restaurants?$    all_rest.php?loc=hk    [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^kw/restaurants?$    all_rest.php?loc=kw    [NC,L,QSA]
```

When my url say www.mywebsite.com/hk/restaurants the browser show me the right file

I have only this at the moment and is working but now I have added a tab system with bootstrap:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#"><h1 class="title2">Restaurants</h1></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><h1 class="title2">Cuisines</h1></a></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the tag `a` has a `href` with `#` so when I click the url change to www.mysite.com/# and I am redirected to the index again

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

A link with just `#` in the href will never cause a navigation to happen on it's own. `#` followed by some characters will cause the browser to try to move the element with that name/id to the top of the page. If nothing appear in front of the `#` it will do so on the *current* page.

The problem is likely with the underlying javascript of the "tab system" you are using. This is not a problem with .htaccess though, but just likely a configuration issue.

Comment: the problem is with my base element on the head of all pages :S when I use # it redirect to my root folder

Comment: I guess that is a possibility too. Whatever the case is, javascript isn't canceling the navigation as it should. `event.preventDefault()` should be called as soon as the click handler fires.